emitting message to client socket has inconsistent behaviour
I have set up Socket.IO in my Express server and React Native app.
Current Flow:
Customer places an order and emits receiveOrder to the server.
Server emits newOrder to the client (restaurant).
The client (restaurant) should receive the new order data.
The Issue:
When trying to send to the client, sometimes the data is received and sometimes not. I fetch the client socket using the ID that was appended on connection, then emit the message. Previously, I stored all connected client sockets in an array on the server, but this was not good behavior since it is stored temporarily. Now, I'm using const allSocketUsers = await io.fetchSockets(); and looping through it to find the client to send the order to using the ID.
Note that I'm running my Express server in clusters and have used @socket.io/cluster-adapter along with @socket.io/sticky to handle cluster operations.
Any explanation or help of what is went wrong it is much appreciated
Below is how I set up the server:

const numCPUs = os.cpus().length;
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
env.config();

if (cluster.isPrimary) {
  console.log(`Primary ${process.pid} is running`);
  // Setup Socket.IO primary adapter
  setupPrimary();
  const httpServer = createServer();
  setupMaster(httpServer, {
    loadBalancingMethod: "least-connection",
  });

  httpServer.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server is listening on port ${PORT}`);
  });

  // Fork workers
  for (let i = 0; i < numCPUs; i++) {
    cluster.fork();
  }

  cluster.on("exit", (worker, code, signal) => {
    console.log(`Worker ${worker.process.pid} died. Forking a new one.`);
    cluster.fork();
  });
} else {
  const app = express();
  app.use(morgan("dev"));
  app.use(express.json());
  app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
  app.use(cookieParser());

  app.use(
    cors({
      origin: "*",
      methods: ["GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE"],
    })
  );
  // Setup routes
  app.use("/api/user", UserRoutes);
  // rest of app routes......

  /* create server */
  const httpServer = createServer(app);
  const io = new Server(httpServer, {
    cors: {
      origin: "*",
      methods: ["GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE"],
    },
  });
  /* attach socket io cluster to handle multi threading  */
  io.adapter(createAdapter());

  // Setup sticky session worker Thus client will always connect to same worker server
  setupWorker(io);
  const PORTWorker = parseInt(process.env.PORT) || 3000 + cluster.worker.id;

  httpServer.listen(PORTWorker, () => {
    console.log(`Worker ${process.pid} started on port ${PORTWorker}`);
  });

  /* ====================START============== */
  /* socket implmenetation */
  io.on("connection", async (socket: Socket) => {
    const id = socket?.handshake?.query["user-ID"] as string;
    // add userId to connected socket
    socket.data = {
      userId: id.toString(),
    };

    socket.on("receiveOrder", async (data) => {
      const { clientId, order } = data;
      const allConnectedSockets = await io.fetchSockets();

      const restaurantSocket = allConnectedSockets?.find((userSocket) => {
        return userSocket.data.userId == clientId;
      });

      if (restaurantSocket) {
        //emit notifyClient to the client
        restaurantSocket.emit("newOrder", { ...order });
      }
    });

    socket.on("disconnect", () => {
      socket.disconnect();
      console.log(
        "client disocunnected: ",
        socket?.handshake?.query["user-ID"]
      );
    });
  });

  /* ======================[END WS]===================== */
}

Probably the way looking up the client socket to emit data to not the perfect way to do.
on other side, in the client side, this is how restaurant is connected in listing to incoming orders:
  useEffect(() => {
    const socket = io.connect('https://xxxx.xx', {
      query: {
        'user-ID': user.user_id,
        role: 'restaurant',
      },
    });
    socket.on('connect', () => {
      console.log('restaurant socket connected');
    });

   //listening to incoming order
    socket.on('newOrder', async (data) => {
      console.log('new order created', data);
      //handle incoming new orders ...

    });

    return () => {
      socket.disconnect();
    };
  }, [isFoucsed]);


On the frontend, initialize the socket globally using useRef instead of a variable inside useEffect. For example, keep a global variable in your constants file:
export const socketRef = createRef();

Then in your App.js, initialize the socket like this:
const socket = useMemo(() => {
  return io('YOUR_SOCKET_URL', {
    reconnectionDelayMax: 5000,
    // reconnection: true,
    forceNew: false,
    transports: ['websocket'],
  });
}, []);

In the useEffect, assign the socket to the global reference and connect it:
useEffect(() => {
  socketRef.current = socket;
  socketRef.current.connect();
}, []);

Moreover, instead of listening to events in the useEffect of a specific screen, listen globally in the main navigation file. Once the restaurant or user is logged in, you can handle socket events regardless of which screen the user is on. The useEffect would look like this:
useEffect(() => {
  if (restaurant) {
    socketRef.current.on('newOrder', handleNewOrder);
  }

  return () => {
    socketRef.current?.off('newOrder');
  };
}, [restaurant]);

